# Mysql Trigger with condition and calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Im using mysql trigger to insert **contribution** from **After insert task table** i need to calculate total hours (**total_hours = new.hours + new. overtime**) and i need to select total_hours from **contribution** table

This is mysql trigger im using but its not working

```
     CREATE TRIGGER update_hours AFTER INSERT ON tasks
     FOR EACH ROW 
     BEGIN
     SELECT p_id d_id hours overtime total_hours FROM contribution WHERE 
      p_id == new.p_id && d_id == new.d_id 

     new.total_hours = total_hours + new.hours + new.overtime


 INSERT INTO contribution
      ( p_id,
       d_id,
       hours,
       overtime,
       total_hours,
       contribution )
       VALUES
          ( NEW.p_id,
            NEW.d_id,
            NEW.hours,
            NEW.overtime,
            new.total_hours,
            NEW.contribution );
      END IF;

 END
```

i need to get values form contribution table and add there values to hours and overtime

I need to insert to the contribution table when add a task hours and overtime. need to calculate total hours (hours + overtime) and add to contribution total_hours .

Comment: Instead of ```new.total_hours```, use ```SET @total_hours```. IOW, use a variable not a pseudo column name. Also, you should edit your question to show the whole trigger definition, not just it's content. There could be a problem in the type of trigger you're creating.

Comment: Also, the first select statement's column list isn't written correctly - no commas, and columns you do not need. You could simple set the variable value in the select statement.

Comment: can you correct it for me

Comment: i dont remember correct syntax i just write a code like a pseudo code  can you help me to re write it i spend to much time on this still cant figure out help me

Comment: Can you add the full text of the trigger definition? You ask for help, but ignore requests for information in the comments.

Comment: do u mean like that i update my code

Comment: First correction: `SELECT p_id , d_id , hours , overtime , total_hours FROM...`.

Comment: Second correction: `WHERE p_id = new.p_id AND d_id = new.d_id`. You are writing SQL(!).

Comment: Third correction: What are the variables `new....`. That is not a legal syntax unless `new` is the name of a table or an alias.

Comment: can you post corrected code ?

Comment: @FDavidov Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.-https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Ah!! OK, forgot about that. Thanks for refreshing my memory. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to get a total of previous entries in contribution.
Step two is to add the new values inserted into tasks, and add to the total.
Step three is to insert the results into contribution.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER update_hours AFTER INSERT ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @old_total_hours = (SELECT SUM(hours + overtime)
        FROM contribution 
        WHERE p_id == new.p_id && d_id == new.d_id 
        GROUP BY p_id);

    SET @total_hours = @old_total_hours + new.hours + new.overtime;

    INSERT INTO contribution
    ( p_id,
    d_id,
    hours,
    overtime,
    total_hours,
    contribution )
    VALUES
    ( 
        NEW.p_id,
        NEW.d_id,
        NEW.hours,
        NEW.overtime,
        @total_hours,
        NEW.contribution
    );
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors here 1) there is a dangling as statement 2) Null safe equal in mysql is <=> (not ==) 3) there is an end if but no if

Comment: For the ```END IF;``` I just copied/pasted the OPs code, but missed that. Anyway, thanks for the catch. I've updated the code.

Comment: hey now i need to calculate contribution in a project (p_id) per a developer(d_id) using total_hours

Comment: Different issue, so ask a new question.

Comment: can u help me to i need to submit my school assignment  with 2h :(

Comment: It's a simple select, but you need to ask a new question. We're not here to do your homework, but to help  you when you get stuck.